# Test Automation architecture

Tags: testing, architecture, automation

My company at the beginning of building Test Automation architecture.
There are different types of apps: windows desktop, web, mobile.

What would you experienced folks recommend to start from?
I mean resources.
Building whole system or construct something basic and enhancing in future?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The company I work with develop web apps, we use several different things, such as qunit for basic javascript testing. We built our own monitor for catching and linting errors to developers on our production sites. We catch a lot of issues mainly with code reviews with small groups though.

Comment: It might be too late for you at this point, but you should consider using an existing framework, that already covers all the aspects mentioned in the answers below. It's really hard to develop an automation tool the proper way. Take a look at the open source tool [OpenTest](https://getopentest.org). Disclaimer: I am a contributor. If you have questions, post an issue in the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2):

Start small.  If you don't know what you need, build the smallest thing you can that adds value.

It's very likely that the first thing you build will *not* be what you need, and that you will need to scrap it and do something else.

Finally, don't try and test EVERYTHING.  This is what I see fail over and over.  Most automated test suites die under their own weight.  Someone makes the decision that EVERYTHING must be tested, and so you build 10,000 tests around every CSS change.  This then costs a fortune to update when the requirements change.  And then you get the requirement to make the bar blue instead of red...

One of two things happen, either the tests get ignored, and the suite dies, or the business compromises what it wants because the tests cost so much to update.  In the first case, the investment in tests was a complete waste, the second case is even more dangerous, it implies that the test suite is actually impeding progress, not assisting it.

Automate the most important tests.  Find the most important workflows.  The analysis of what to test should take more time than writing the tests themselves.

Finally, embrace the [Pyramid of Tests](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just as Rob Conklin said,

1. Start small
2. Identify the most important tests
3. Build your test automation architecture around these tests
4. Ensure your architecture allows for reusability and manageability
5. Build easily understandable report and error logs
6. Add Test Data Management to your architecture

Once you ensure all these, you can enhance later as you add new tests

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what was already mentioned:

- Make sure you have fast feedback from your automated tests. Ideally they should be executed after each commit to master branch.
- Identify in which areas of your system test automation brings the biggest value.
- Start from integration tests and leave end-to-end tests for a while
- Try to keep every automated test very small and checking only one function
- Prefer low level test interface like API, CLI over GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious on what path you chose. We run UI automated tests for mobile, desktop applications, and web.

Always start small but building a framework is what I recommend as the first steps when facing this problem.

The approach we took is:

- create mono repo
- installed [selenium webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/projects/) for web
- installed [winapp driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) for desktop
- installed [appium](https://appium.io/) for mobile
- created an api for each system

  - DesktopApi
  - WebApi
  - MobileApi

These APIs contain business functions that we share across teams.

This builds our framework to now write tests going across the different systems such as:

1. create a user on mobile device
2. enter a case for them in our desktop
3. application login on the web as the user and check balance

Before getting started on the framework it is always best to learn from others [test automation mistakes](https://learntestautomation.com/test-automation-mistakes/).

Answer (score 0):

Start with prioritizing which tests should be automated such as business critical features, repetitive tests that must be executed for every build or release (smoke tests, sanity tests, regression tests), data-driven tests, and stress and load testing. If your application supports different operating systems and browsers, it’s highly useful to automate tests early that verifies stability and proper page rendering.

In the initial stages of building your automation framework, keep the tests simple and gradually include more complex tests. And in all cases, the tests should be easily maintained, and you need to consider how you will debug errors, report on test results, scheduling tests, and bulk test runs.